# What does this 'emoji code' do?

Tags: c++, c, unicode, identifier, deobfuscation

I think this is C code, but I'm not entirely sure. I found it in a few persons' online signatures, and in SO chat once. I tried compiling it, but received a really hard to read error taking issue with the unusual characters presented.

Does it do anything? I have no idea what to do with this in my head.

```
enum ಠ_ಠ {°□°╰=1, °Д°╰, ಠ益ಠ╰};
void ┻━┻︵​╰(ಠ_ಠ ⚠) {exit((int)⚠);}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile with a C compiler; the function argument would have to be of type `enum ಠ_ಠ`.  It might compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Those aren't emojis

Comment: @DYZ both [C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier) and [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) now support Unicode identifiers

Comment: @DYZ: In C11, §5.1.1.2 Translation phases, phase 1 starts with: _Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation defined
manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for
end-of-line indicators) if necessary._  Those are multibyte characters that are mapped in an implementation defined manner.  That might, I suppose, be mapped to an error, but some compilers might not reject it.  There's also Annex D which defines which defines 'Universal character names for identifiers', giving limits on which characters may be used in identifiers.

Comment: Don't they have to be entered ax \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX?

Comment: @DYZ: Not in C++. The compiler does that in phase 1: "Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character." (From C++ [lex.phases])

Comment: Okay.
Why is _this_ question poor and downvote deserving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid C, but it might be accepted by a tolerant C++ compiler. If so, it doesn't "do" anything; it only declares a datatype and defines a function.

In C++, `class`, `union`, `struct` and `enum` declare typenames. In C, you need to use a `typedef` to achieve approximately the same effect (approximately, because you can't declare a typename in a scope in C). So the line:

```
enum ಠ_ಠ {°□°╰=1, °Д°╰, ಠ益ಠ╰};
```

declares a type called `ಠ_ಠ`, which is an `enum` with three members corresponding to constants `1`, `2` and `3`. (Note 1)

Since `ಠ_ಠ` is a typename, it can then be used as such. In particular, you can declare the function `┻━┻︵​╰` (Note 2):

```
void ┻━┻︵​╰(ಠ_ಠ ⚠) {exit((int)⚠);}
```

which takes a `ಠ_ಠ` as an argument named `⚠` (Note 3), casts it to an `int` and then calls the standard C library function `exit` with that value.

---

#### Notes

1. The enum typename is fine, but all of the member names include characters not on the list of valid identifier characters in the current C++ standard. A tolerant C++ compiler might allow them as an extension. (However, neither clang nor gcc do.) In particular, the degree symbol U+00B0 `°` is not a valid identifier character, and neither is U+2570 `╰`, the light arc up and right box drawing character. In fact, none of the box drawing characters are valid identifier characters, including the white square U+25A1 `□`.
2. Most of those characters are *not* valid identifier characters. There are six characters in that name: three heavy box drawing characters, a vertical left parenthesis, a zero-width space, and a light box drawing character. Curiously, the zero-width space is a valid identifier character even though it is more or less invisible. The rotated parenthesis is also valid, but the four box-drawing characters are not, as mentioned above.
3. The "warning sign" `⚠` is also not on the list of valid identifier characters.

Answer (score 3):

Let's deobfuscate this.

```
enum eyes {a=1, b, c};
void f(eyes e) {exit((int)e);}
```

So basically it defines a function that aborts the program execution with an exit code from an enum type.

It won't work in C though.